# How do I provide the missing 404 handling for Visual Studio's Blazor Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I am mainly using `Interactive render mode: WebAssembly` and `Interactivity location: Global`, but the issue exists with each template setting. Can someone give me an indication of what I need to do to implement a simple 404 page?

**Update:** I was told to add `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute( "/StatusCode/{0}" );` to my `Program.cs` (in this case, the server-side one), and then add a page `StatusCode.razor` (in this case, on the client) to output the status code:

```cs
@page "/StatusCode/{ResponseCode}"

@inherits MainLayout;

<p>@this.ResponseCode</p>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? ResponseCode { get; set; }
}
```

This seems to work, but then a moment later it gets replaced with a blank page displaying only `Not found`. I assume this is due to some middleware or other, but I have further idea at the moment.

Comment: Maybe error boundaries: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/handle-errors?view=aspnetcore-8.0#error-boundaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an easy way to do through `MapFallback`.

server-side **Program.cs**

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

var app = builder.Build();

...

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(BlazorApp1.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("404page.html");

app.Run();
```

client-side **wwwroot/404page.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Sorry, we couldn't find the page you're looking for</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: Well, that meets the requirements of the question. I guess it also gives me a place to look for more options to report the nature of routing errors or whatever could apply.